# populating a select list from javascript when value contains spaces

Tags: jquery, selectlist

Im making an ajax call to retrieve some data that I use to populate a select list. If the text contains spaces Its being split up when the value is populated.  Ive tried various suggestions but none of them work.  For example, If the data is

"Cost risk report"

the select list is being populated like this

```html
<option value="Cost" risk="" report="">Cost Risk Report</option>
```

This is the code Ive used to populate the list

```js
response.forEach(function (obj) {
                            if ($("#multiselect_toRpt option[value='" + obj.ReportName + "']").length == 0) {
                                var optionSelect = "<option value='" + obj.ReportName + "'>" + obj.ReportName + "</option>"
                                $('#multiselectReport').append(optionSelect);
                            }
                            
                       });
```

can anyone help ?

Comment: It would make it more clear if you say you want to capitalize first letter of words across the text rather than getting the text "split up" by spaces.

Comment: could it be any clearer ? I want all of the text to be in the value, its being split up

Comment: value should be this   <option value="Energy costs report">Energy Costs Report</option>

Answer (score 0):

Before you put the text into the `select` element, use the `replace()` method.

e.g.

```
 var str=response.replace(/ /g,'');
```

Then you can use that variable in all your code.